# How can I generate an Admin grid programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, grid-layout

I can add a form to an Admin page using the code below in a Block:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $item = $this->registry->registry('current_item');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('score_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Stuff')]);
    if ($item->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('item_id', 'hidden', [
            'name' => 'item_id',
            'value' => $item->getId(),
        ]);
    }
    $fieldset->addField('entries_num', 'text', [
        'label' => __('Number of Entries'),
        'name' => 'entries_num',
        'value' => $item->getEntriesNum(),

    ]);
    $fieldset->addField('score', 'text', [
        'label' => __('Score'),
        'name' => 'score',
        'value' => round($item->getScore(), 1),

    ]);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

However, I would like to add the form as an editable grid of all the scores/entries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link for creating admin grid

[Create admin grid in Magento 2](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/amp/)

And for Inline edit content

[Inline Edit Component](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-inline.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking if it's possible without using an xml file.